# Can a fair coin be used to simulate an arbitrary weighted coin, with on average only two flips?

Tags: computer-puzzle, probability

This puzzle was told to me by a Stanford PhD student in a graduate course on randomized algorithms. It's really clever/beautiful, and I think makes for a great challenge.

***You are given a fair coin, and your goal is to simulate a biased coin with an arbitrary(!) bias. On average, your method must terminate in 2 coin flips. You can have any probability p, p=1/pi, p=1/17, p=.25, etc.***

To make this a bit more formal, I'll give some pseudo-code.

```
# flip() -> returns true with probably 1/2
# flip() is the only source of randomness allowed.
def biased_flip(p):
   """
   Returns true with probability p.
   """
   ... # TODO: implement me!

# if we call biased_flip() a million times, we will
# expect flip() to have been called on average 2 million times
# Any individual call could flip more than twice, but expectation is 2 per call. 
for i in range(10e6):
   biased_flip(random.uniform())
```

I promise it's possible.

Hint 1:

> The solution begins with turning the probability p into a binary decimal string. For example, 1/4=0.01.

Hint 2:

> k coin flips can be turned into a binary decimal, which will partition the interval [0, 1] into 2^k subintervals. Each of these subintervals are equally likely. As k approaches infinity, are able to sample essentially uniformly from [0, 1].

Hint 3:

> Keep flipping the coin, and with each flip, build up a binary string. 1 if the flips is H, 0 if T. The flips HHTT -> 0.1100. If your binary string is below the expansion of p so far, will it ever go above? If it's above, will it ever go below?

Hint 4:

> 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 converges to 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Well, it's very simple.
>  Let's write $p$ as a (possibly infinite) binary fraction: $p=0.p_1p_2p_3\dots$, where $p_i$ is either 0 or 1.
>  Next, start tossing the coin, generating number $q=0.q_1q_2\dots q_k$ (where $q_i$ is the result of the $i$-th toss, 1=heads and 0=tails, or vice versa), until that value of $k$ where it becomes clear if $q<p$ or $q>p$ (equality can be treated in the either case). (For example, if $p_1=0$ and $q_1=1$, it's clear then $q\geqslant p$, since $0.1_2=0.011111\dots_2$, so we stop at $k=1$).
>  Now, there is a question. How frequently will we stop after $k$ tosses? Well, we need exactly $k$ flips if and only if $p_i=q_i \forall i=1,2,\dots,k-1$ , but $p_k\neq q_k$. Probability of that is $\frac{1}{2^k}$, since $q_i$ are independent (and have a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\frac12$).
>  So, the average number of tosses is $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n\times\frac{1}{2^n}=2$$
>  (The latter is proven by the fact that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^n}=\frac{2}{2-x} (-2\leqslant x < 2)$, thus by differentiating $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}{2^n}=\frac{2}{(2-x)^2}$. Plugging $x=1$ (which is well within the radius of convergence) gives the result.)

Comment: I would not call this very simple!

Answer (score 1):

(Note: Please forgive my lack of math formatting ability.)

```
 bool biased_flip(decimal p)
 {
    decimal stepSize = .5;
    decimal accumulation = 0;
    while (accumulation < p && accumulation + stepSize * 2 > p)
    {
        if(flip())
        {
            accumulation += stepSize;
        }
        stepSize /= 2;
    }
    return accumulation >= p;
}
```

Because it's a computer puzzle, I wrote a (pseudo) program! How does it work?

Since we're relating coin flips to probability p, 0<p<1, I

> related individual flips of the coin to positive integral powers of 1/2 (stepSize)

because

> the sum of all such values converges to 1

and

> any positive value less than 1 can be represented by a subset of this sum

So the nth flip of the fair coin represents

> The nth power of 1/2

Each true result of flip()

> Adds the corresponding power of 1/2 to a running total (accumulation) for the current biased_flip().

Each false result of flip()

> Does not add the corresponding power of 1/2, but skips it.

The result of the biased flip is decided when

> Either accumulation meets/exceeds p (true), or accumulation can no longer meet/exceed p (false).

Essentially, we're using fair coin flips to

> generate a random number, which is then compared with p

but the method terminates when enough information is gathered to

> determine whether p or the new random number is greater.

Finally, how do we know the average number of fair coin flips per biased flip is 2?

> Every flip of the fair coin terminates the biased flip 50% of the time

That is, exactly one of the following is true at each flip:

> A true flip() will result in accumulation meeting/exceeding p, so the biased_flip() returns true. (when accumulation + stepSize >= p)

or

> A false flip() will leave the value of accumulation too low to reach p with any number of subsequent true flip()s, so the biased_flip() returns false. (when accumulation + stepSize < p)

Thus we are guaranteed to flip the fair coin at least once for each biased flip, and each additional fair flip occurs

> with half the probability of the previous flip, on average.

The average number of fair flips per biased flip is therefore

> 1 + all positive integral powers of 1/2

= 2